# showing part of the video in android

Tags: android, video, media-player

I am developing an application for video wall like support. So I need to show some part of the video in the screen. Some part of the video means :

suppose I have a video of resolution **600*400 px** and of length **10 min**. I want to show the specific pixels to the users not the specific length. I mean let I want to show **300*200 px (0 px to 300 px width and 0 px to 200 px height)**.

I am thinking about these three options to achieve this

1. Extend VideoView/Mediaplayer to play only specific coordinates of the video.
2. Set the layout parameters of videoview to specific values, that will make only a part of the video to be visible on the screen.
3. Convert the video to number of image frames and the split those image bitmaps as per the requirement and then merge those small image chunks again to form the video.

I want to know which option is better for me. Please suggest a good one so that I can proceed on that way. If you have some other better option, then please suggest that. Please don't forget to mention why your suggestion is better than others.

If you know some links which can help me achieving this, please share it.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, can you tell me how you acheived this?

Comment: @Shubendra, I have failed to achieve this.